# Ship Yalkut Yosef New Version

Tags: jewish-books, hacham-ovadia-yosef, israel

It seems the Yalkut Yosef has been revised and now includes a total of 32 volumes, comprised of 3 boxes. Unfortunately, all the sets I see online or in the U.S. are of the older 24-volume edition, which has fewer seforim for Mo'adim and other changes. I believe since it was only recently updated it can only be found in Israel and at their direct website where I don't see an option to ship to the US (see [link](https://yalkutyosef.co.il/product/%D7%A1%D7%98-%D7%99%D7%9C%D7%A7%D7%95%D7%98-%D7%99%D7%95%D7%A1%D7%A3-%D7%94%D7%9E%D7%9C%D7%90-37-%D7%9B%D7%A8%D7%9B%D7%99%D7%9D/)).

Anyone know how I could possibly acquire the updated set?

Comment: Have you tried to get in touch with the publisher to see about them shipping to the States?

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) Elie and thanks for this first question. Great to have you learn with us!

Answer (score 5):

Shalom and welcome aboard, Elie!

Chacham Yitzchak Yosef has updated all the Moadim volumes over the past decade, and they are sold separately. Ultimately, they only replace one volume of the old set. In addition, he updated the first volume of Hilchot Shabbat before that and split it into more volumes. Those are sometimes sold separately and sometimes as a set. You should definitely get those newer volumes, as they incorporate updated pesakim from Chazon Ovadia plus many many more sources and discussions including more contemporary sefarim quoting Rav Shlomo Zalman Auerbach and Rav Elyashiv.

They can all be purchased from local Jewish bookstores in the US. Take a look at [ZBermanBooks.com](https://ZBermanBooks.com), [JudaicaPlaza.com](https://JudaicaPlaza.com), [Eichlers.com](https://Eichlers.com), [ShopEichlers.com](https://ShopEichlers.com), [MekorJudaica.com](https://MekorJudaica.com), [Nehora.com](https://Nehora.com), [SeforimCenter.com](https://SeforimCenter.com), [JudaicaSpot.com](https://judaicaspot.com/), [SeforimSets.com](https://SeforimSets.com), Biegeleisen, [GreenfeldJudaica.com](https://GreenfeldJudaica.com), [SephardicWarehouse.com](https://www.sephardicwarehouse.com/search?type=product&q=yalkut%20yosef*), [MySefer.com](https://mysefer.com/Search.aspx?strSearchText=yalkut%20yosef), etc.

You can probably get a good deal plus free shipping from Judaica Plaza or Shop Eichlers, but ZBerman often has the best or at least a competitive price. Contact them if you need anything, and they'll get it for you if they can. No need to purchase and ship something from Israel when you can have it here in a couple days from a local store.

He also redid the volume on Sheviit seven years ago, but I haven't checked to see which one comes in the current set.

Many of the new volumes are available for free on [HebrewBooks.org](https://www.hebrewbooks.org/home.aspx) (free) and, of course, and [Otzar Hachochmah](https://otzar.org) (paid). Bar Ilan's [Responsa.co.il](https://responsa.co.il) does not have all the new volumes.

Comment: Thank you very much. Just to be clear, does the 24 volume set include the updated Shabbat, or is that only sold separately? My understanding is I should purchase the 24 volume set and Moadim set (and also the Shabbat set if not updated).

Comment: I would recommend emailing any of the stores to clarify.